# Calculating the expectation of $X_{1} = a + bX_{2} + X_{3}$ where $X_{2}$ and $X_{3}$ are independent from each other and both normal distributed

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

$\newcommand{\E}[1]{\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[#1]}$

So I will just show what I have done, I think I am fairly close to a correct solution, if not the correct solution.

So this is the setup:
$$
X_{1} = a + bX_{2} + X_{3}
$$
$$
X_{2} = N(\mu_{2}, \sigma^{2}_{2})
$$
$$
X_{3} = N(\mu_{3}, \sigma^{2}_{3})
$$

And then I want to calculate $\E{X_{1}} = \E{a + bX_{2} + X_{3}} $.
By using linearity and the $\E{a+bX} = a + b\E{X}$ rule and the rule that if $X_{2}$ and $X_{3}$ are independent their expectation can just be added together, I get:

$$
\E{X_{1}} = \E{a + bX_{2} + X_{3}} = a + b\E{X_{2}} + \E{X_{3}} 
$$

The expectation of a normal distributed variable $X_{2}$ and $X_{3}$ is just its respective $\mu$ parameter. So I get:
$$
a + b\E{X_{2}} + \E{X_{3}} = a + b\mu_{2} + \mu_{3}
$$
At this point, I am not sure what else to do with the statement, is this my final result? I think that maybe I am mixing up expectation with some variance rules, where a constant like $a$ just disappears?

Comment: That’s it. For the linearity of expectation one does not even need independence. It’s needed to find variance of the sum only

Comment: @Ilya Yeah alright, thanks !

Comment: And the same procedure if you are dealing with other distributions than the normal.